# modal + ajax, не работает кнопка отправить

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть модальное окно в таком виде (на сайте очень много форм)

```
`$('.btn-evacuator').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.form-container').removeClass('hidden').html('<div class="form-block">\n' +
            '        <h3>Вызвать </h3>\n' +
            '        <form class="ajax-form>\n' +
            '            <input type="hidden" name="whatform" value="Форма - Вызов" />\n' +
            '            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" size="25" required="">\n' +
            '            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required="">\n' +
            '            <button id="send" class="button cta_b" type="button">Отправить</button>\n' +
            '        </form>\n' +
            '        <button type="button" class="btn-close">×</button>\n' +
            '    </div>');
        $('body').toggleClass('lock');
    });`

форма отправлялась просто в php и потом на страницу благодарности, теперь хочу отправлять через ajax и что-то никакой реакции на кнопку



$("#send").on('click', function () {
     $.ajax({
        url: "/mail.php",
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            alert("ok")
        }
     });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.form-container').on('click', "#send", function () {
```

---

```
$(document).on('click', "#send", function () {
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло